# Why doesn't my jquery work when I add <form> tags?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form that displays an animation when it opens and closes:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">
#contactFormContainer
            {
                width:300px;
                margin-top:15px;
            }
            #contactForm
            {
                margin-top:15px;
                width:300px;
                border:solid 1px #4d3a24;
                display:none;
            }
            #contactForm fieldset
            {
                padding:20px;
                border:none;
            }      
            #contactForm label
            {
                display:block;
            }      
            #contactForm input[type=text]
            {
                display:block;
                border:solid 1px #4d3a24;
                width:100%;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                height:24px;
            }  
            #contactForm textarea
            {
                display:block;
                border:solid 1px #4d3a24;
                width:100%;
                margin-bottom:10px;
            }  
            #contactForm input[type=submit]
            {
                background-color:#4d3a24;
                border:solid 1px #23150c;
                color:#FFFFFF;
                padding:5px;
                cursor:pointer;
                float: right;
            }                
            #contactLink
            {
                height:15px;
                width:218px;
                background-image:url('../images/signup.png');
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            #messageSent
            {
                color:#bc0d1b;
                display:none;
            }
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#contactLink").click(function(){
        if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")){
            $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
        }else{
            $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
        }
    });

});

function closeForm(){
    $("#messageSent").show("slow");
    setTimeout('$("#messageSent").hide();$("#contactForm").slideUp("slow")', 2000);
}
</script>

</head><body>



    <div id="contactFormContainer">
        <div id="contactLink"></div>
        <div id="contactForm">
            <form action="test2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Name *</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
                <label for="email">Email address *</label>
                <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
                <input id="sendMail" type="submit" name="signupSubmit" />
                <span id="messageSent"></span>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that if I add `<form action="test2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">` above the first fieldset - and then close the form... my closing animation no longer works.

**TL;DR**

1. I click submit and the form closes in a nice annimation
2. I add a `<form>` tag so that I can process the POST
3. The closing animation nolonger works

Why, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coldhead in Freenode's #jquery channel answered it with the following: http://jsfiddle.net/d9AfJ/7/

Answer (score 1):

When you have a form, the button press is instead translated into a form submit, not an onclick. You need to intercept the form submit event like so:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) { do animation here } )
```